# Split video file into pieces with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, shell-script, ffmpeg

When you want to extract two minutes of a video file from minute 2 to minute 4, you will use command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:02:00 -t 00:02:00 output.mpg
```

I'd like to split the video into two minutes chunks. I have an idea to use a bash script, but there are a few errors.

```
for i in seq 50;
do ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:`expr $i \* 2 - 2`:00 -t 00:02:00 output.mpg; done
```

Do you know how to correct the errors in script that are where I use `$i` expression? Or is there some better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to use backticks - or better: `$( )` subshell - in the `seq` invocation. This works:

```
for i in $( seq 50 );
do ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:`expr $i \* 2 - 2`:00 -t 00:02:00 output.mpg; done
```

Another thing is that you probably don't want `output.mpg` to be overwritten in each run, do you? :) Use `$i` in the output filename as well.

Apart from that: In bash, you can just use `$(( ))` or `$[ ]` instead of `expr` - it also looks more clear (in my opinion). Also, there is no need for `seq` - brace expansion is all you need to get a sequence. Here's an example:

```
for i in {1..50}
 do ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:$[ i* 2 - 2 ]:00 -t 00:02:00 output_$i.mpg
done
```

Another good thing about braces is that you can have leading zeros in the names (very useful for file sorting in the future):

```
for i in {01..50}
 do ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:$[ i* 2 - 2 ]:00 -t 00:02:00 output_$i.mpg
done
```

Notice as well, that `i*2 - 2` can be easily simplified to `i*2` if you just change the range:

```
for i in {00..49}
 do ffmpeg -i input.mpg -sameq -ss 00:$[ i*2 ]:00 -t 00:02:00 output_$i.mpg
done
```

Comment: Thank you, it's great to learn these features when I need them.