# FFmpeg - Split video multiple parts

Tags: ffmpeg, split, video-editing

I read the following thread, and the solution works if I want to split a video into pieces every two minutes: [Split video file into pieces with ffmpeg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22585/split-video-file-into-pieces-with-ffmpeg)

The problem is that I want to split a video into pieces every 15 seconds.

When I use the following command:

```
for i in {00..49}
 do ffmpeg -i fff.avi -sameq -ss 00:$[ i*2 ]:00 -t 00:00:15 output_$i.avi
done
```

it will output 15-second video sequences, but not in order. It will skip parts of the video, so I end up with a few 15 second clips, but not all the clips. I want to be able to use ffmpeg to split any video I throw at it into many pieces based on the time I give it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the answer. It turns out I was having problems because I didn't have the proper FFmpeg installed, but a fork of ffmpeg.

This code works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i fff.avi -acodec copy -f segment -segment_time 10 -vcodec copy -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0 fff%d.avi
```

`fff.avi` is the name of the source clip. Change `-segment_time 10` to the general duration you want for each segment. If you want each clip to be about 40 seconds, then use `-segment_time 40`. Use `-an` after `-map 0` if you don't want the resulting clips to have sound.

Comment: Too bad that I have run the command at first, deleted the source video and have read about `-an` flag at last.

Comment: @Pehat That's unfortunate. I removed `-an` from the code. You might be able to retrieve your source video with Photorec: http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Rescuing-Lost-Files-with-TestDisk-and-PhotoRec