# Split video file into chunks using FFMPEG and exact number of frames

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to split a video `video.avi` (with `N` being the total number of frames) into contiguous chunks according to a fixed number of frames (say `M = 100`).
Specifically this process should yield:

1. `video_0.avi`: Frames 0 to `M-1`
2. `video_1.avi`: Frames `M` to `2M-1`
3. `video_2.avi`: Frames `2M` to `3M-1`
4. ...

It is important that each chunk `video_*.avi` has exactly `M` frames. Therefore, the last chunk can be discarded if `N` is not divisible by `M`.

I found related issues (e.g. [Split video file into pieces with ffmpeg](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22585/split-video-file-into-pieces-with-ffmpeg)) but find myself struggling to replace the specification in **seconds** with the **number of frames**.

Comment: With codecs such as H.264 there isn't really a hard relationship between frames and time. There are incremental pre-frames and incremental post-frames, with a full reference frame only every so often. You can't easily chop during a pre-frame section because the reference frame on which these pre-frames depend hasn't yet been encountered.

Comment: You can only split by `I` frames and as @roaima has mentioned there's no guarantee they are evenly spread.

Comment: Okay thank you very much to both of you!

Comment: "With codecs such as H.264 there isn't really a hard relationship between frames and time" -- can you name one that is? That's what I'm actually trying to find out, so that I can convert a video to a format where I can split it without the headache that H264/H265 are causing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first chunk, you should be able to use `-vframes M-1` and it will be OK (even for `-c copy` if I recall).

The other chunks are trickier, and I've had no success with:
`-vf 'select=gte(n\,M)'` -- it needs re-encoding anyway, but does strange things with different codecs -- e.g. leaves the preceding duration with a still frame, and plays the sound...

You can get the time in seconds by dividing the frame numbers through FPS, e.g. if your FPS is `$fps` and M is `$M`:

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -ss `echo "scale=6; $M / $fps" | bc` -to `echo "scale=6; (2 * $M) / $fps" | bc` video_01.avi
```

etc. If you have a scripting language to compute these times, it will be easier. Also, note that when re-encoding (i.e. without `-c copy`), `-ss` and `-to` will be precise, see also: https://superuser.com/questions/459313/how-to-cut-at-exact-frames-using-ffmpeg